# typescript error: 'RRule' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Im trying to implement 'rrule' for my angular calendar. It's showing me an error: [ts] 'RRule' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

```
import RRule from 'rrule';

interface RecurringEvent {
  title: string;
  color: any;
  rrule?: {
    freq: RRule.Frequency;
    bymonth?: number;
    bymonthday?: number;
    byweekday?: RRule.Weekday[];
  };
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you replace your import by import * as RRule from 'rrule'?

Comment: No. It's not working

Comment: It's wokring now, by changing: import RRule from 'rrule' to
import RRule, { Frequency, Weekday } from 'rrule'; and remove RRule from freq and byweekday

Comment: @SaiVishnu you need to use `['Frequency']` syntax with types to access the member like that.

Answer (score 1):

it's because on:

```
    freq: RRule.Frequency;
byweekday?: RRule.Weekday[];
```

you are accessing elements from RRule but you don't have an instance from this class. Here I suppose you want to get the type of those elements. You can navigate to the definition of RRule and get those types, then you must have to add their imports too.

Answer (score 1):

Or it should also be possible to use something like

```
  freq: typeof RRule.Frequency;
  ...
```